# как поменять цвет элемента заданного с помощью свойства content

Tags: css, css3, html5

На странице есть элемент

```
.select__gap:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;

    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -7px;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-top: 14px solid #000;

    -webkit-transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .27s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Это стрелочка вниз, которая при клике разворачивается.
Она Чёрного цвета. Как поменять её цвет?. Свойство `color` у `.select__gap` не срабатывает.

Comment: `border-top: 14px solid #000;` задается черный цвет

Comment: @Grundy , спасибо за ответ все перекрасилось, объясните если Вас не затруднит, как это работает. В ответе. Я Вам галочку поставлю. PS прошу не судите строго , я дно фронтенда=)

Comment: @Grundy всмысле объсните почему цвет задаётся через border

Comment: _почему цвет задаётся через border_ - это один из подходов, для рисования треугольника

Comment: @Grundy а-а я понял 3мя рамками рисуется треугольник правильно?,

Comment: формально - одним. но суть верна.

Comment: @Grundy благодаря Вам еще один человек просветился =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отображаемая часть данного элемента задана стилями

```
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
border-top: 14px solid #000;
```

Данная запись свойства `border-*` является сокращенной от

```
border-*-width: ...
border-*-style: ...
border-*-color: ...
```

---

Как можно заметить, у левой и правой границы задается прозрачный цвет, в то время как у верхней границы - черный.

Для перекрашивания достаточно заменить его на нужный.

---

Чтобы стало понятно как это работает, достаточно раскрасить каждую из границ в свой цвет:

```css
.select__gap:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  border-left: 7px solid blue;
  border-right: 7px solid green;
  border-top: 14px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="select__gap"></div>
```